# Вставить перменную в запрос JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой код js

```
var idvalue = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
```

Вместо 0 мне нужно вставить переменную под названием idhide, но я не знаю как, пробовал много вариантов, например этот [+idhide+] или [+(idhide)+], ничего не получается, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Дабра пажолавоть на StackOverflow. Хотелось бы увидеть `html` к этому `js`

Comment: В коде идёт явное получение текста или значения из `input` в `idvalue`.  Если нужно скрыть сам элемент, делается это по другому. Нужно переформулировать вопрос и добавить html для наглядности, что из себя представляет input и сколько их и что толком нужно сделать

Comment: В этой переменной код получения данных из input по индексу, (в данном случае 0), у меня есть переменная с этим самым индексом, вот я ее и хочу вставить вместо 0. Вот idhide var idhide = $('a').index(this);(вычисляется индекс нажатой кнопки и я хочу чтобы он использовался в переменной idvalue).

Comment: Мне кто-нибудь поможет? Местные гуру? Ау

Comment: `input` какой тип имеет, сомневаюсь что файл. Это кнопка или текстовое поле? `<input type='?'>`. Я чую там jquery есть и кнопка ссылкой идёт

Comment: @Fred, по имеющимся данным хватит простого `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[idhide].value`, но возможно вы не правильно определяете индекс, заметьте, что идет попытка определить номер тега `a`, если `this` - это кнопка(input) - то функция `index` вернет `-1`, соответственно при попытке использовать это значение дальше будет ошибка

Comment: @Grundy Вы были абсолютно правы, оказывается я неправильно определял индекс, а я то думал что неправильно вставляю переменную... Спасибо всем за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var idhide = Number(prompt("введите число 0 или 2", "0")); // первым элементом будет тег br
        
function myFunc(){  
   document.getElementById("myForm").children[idhide].value = "новый текст";
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text"><br>
  <input type="text"><br>
  <input type="button" value="изменить поле" onclick="myFunc()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
input = document.querySelectorAll('input');

function get(id) {
  console.log(input[id].value);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' value='shit'>
<input type='text' value='ass'>
<input type='text' value='dick'><br><br>

<button onclick='get(0)'>input 0</button>
<button onclick='get(1)'>input 1</button>
<button onclick='get(2)'>input 2</button>
```

Comment: Толком не понятно что хочет автор, может этот ответ поможет